# Issues with getByClassnameHierarchy implementation

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to implement getByClassnameHierarchy but I'm having issues with implementation. **Should I be using a BFS instead of DFS to traverse nodes?**

Can someone explain me both the methods and Pro's and Con's of using these?

```js
    // Helper function to make output easier to read
const getIds = (elements=[]) => Array.from(elements).map(x => x.id);
    
    /**
     * Return all DOM elements who are _leaf_nodes_ that satisfy the hierarchy. 
     * Hierarchy is a string of class names separated by `>`, akin to 
     * CSS CHILD SELECTORS.
     * 
     * ex. getByClassnameHierarchy(#root, 'a>b>c') -> [<div class="c" id="c-1"></div>,<div class="c" id="c-2"></div> ]
     * "give me all the elements with class name 'c', who have a strict parent with 
     * class name 'b', who have a strict parent with class name 'a'"
     * 
     * @param root DOMElement: start the search from this DOM element
     * @param hierarchy string: `>`-delimited string of classnames
     * @return Array<DOMElement>: all DOM elements that satisfy the target hierarchy
     */
    function getByClassnameHierarchy(root, hierarchy) {
      // parentNode
      const res = [];
      const level = hierarchy.split('>');
      
      helper(root, level, 0);
      return res;
      
      function helper(root, level, cur) {
        
        if(!root) return
        
        if(root.classList && root.classList.contains(level[cur-1])){ // b
          
           if(root.parentNode.classList.contains(level[cur-2])) { // a
              if(root.classList.contains(level[cur-1])) {
                 res.push(root);
                }
            }
           
        } //c
      
        root.childNodes.forEach(child => {
          helper(child, level, cur + 1);
        });
      
      }
    }

    
    const root2 = document.getElementById('root2');

    // // basic case:
    console.log('actual: ', getIds(getByClassnameHierarchy(root2, 'a>b>c')));
    console.log(`a>b>c expected:` , `['c-1', 'c-2']`, '\n');
```

```html
    <div id="root2">
      <div class="a" id="a-1">
        <div class="b" id="b-1">
          <div class="c" id="c-1"></div>
          <div class="c" id="c-2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Issue:

Expected is returning:  `[ 'b-1', 'c-1', 'c-2' ]` instead of `['c-1', 'c-2']`

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Please edit your sample to make it runnable (with some HTML in there).

Comment: @Jeto Done :D  I've added the code.

Comment: I mean you could just do `getByClassnameHierarchy(root, hierarchy) { return root.querySelectorAll("."+hierarchy.replace(/>/g,'>.'));}` and be done with it...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol the entire point of me doing this would be to implement it .. I don't want to use querySelectorAll. I've been asked this in an interview. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2020 edit (thanks to @techguy2000's comment)**:

This version should correctly handle cases where the root element itself has some classes. It also fixes a few issues with the previous version:

```js
const getIds = (elements = []) => Array.from(elements).map(x => x.id);

function getByClassnameHierarchy(element, hierarchy, level = 0) {
  const result = [];
  
  const classNames = hierarchy.split('>');
  const currentClassName = classNames[0];
  
  const isClassFound = element.classList && element.classList.contains(currentClassName);
  const isLastClass = classNames.length === 1;
  
  if (isClassFound) {
    if (isLastClass) {
      result.push(element);
    } else {
      element.childNodes.forEach(child => {
        result.push(...getByClassnameHierarchy(child, classNames.slice(1).join('>'), level + 1));
      });
    }
  } 
  
  if (level === 0) {
    element.childNodes.forEach(child => {
      result.push(...getByClassnameHierarchy(child, hierarchy, level));
    });
  }
  
  return result;
}

// Test

const root2 = document.getElementById('root2');

console.log('a>b>c actual:', getIds(getByClassnameHierarchy(root2, 'a>b>c')));
console.log('a>b>c expected:', ['c-1', 'c-2', 'c-3', 'c-4']);

console.log('b>c actual: ', getIds(getByClassnameHierarchy(root2, 'b>c')));
console.log('b>c expected:', ['c-1', 'c-2', 'c-3', 'c-4']);

console.log('b actual: ', getIds(getByClassnameHierarchy(root2, 'b')));
console.log('b expected:', ['b-1', 'b-2']);

console.log('a>c actual: ', getIds(getByClassnameHierarchy(root2, 'a>c')));
console.log('a>c expected:', []);
```

```html
<div class="a" id="root2">
  <div class="a" id="a-1">
    <div class="b" id="b-1">
      <div class="c" id="c-1"></div>
      <div class="c" id="c-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b" id="b-2">
    <div class="c" id="c-3"></div>
    <div class="c" id="c-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Initial answer**:

You could do something like this (check the comments for details):

```js
const getIds = (elements = []) => Array.from(elements).map(x => x.id);

function getByClassnameHierarchy(root, hierarchy, level = 0) {
  let result = [];
  
  // Grab the class names
  const classNames = hierarchy.split('>');
  
  // Retrieve the current (first) one
  const currentClassName = classNames[0];
  
  // For each child
  root.childNodes.forEach(child => {
    // If it contains the given class
    if (child.classList && child.classList.contains(currentClassName)) {
      // Append the result of the following selector on this child, 
      // or the child itself if we're at the last part of the selector
      result = result.concat(classNames.length > 1 
        ? getByClassnameHierarchy(child, classNames.slice(1).join('>'), level + 1)
        : child);
    }
    // Otherwise, if we're still on the first part of the selector, 
    // append the result of the same selector on this child
    else if (level === 0) {
      result = result.concat(getByClassnameHierarchy(child, hierarchy, level));
    }
  });
  
  return result;
}

// Test

const root2 = document.getElementById('root2');

console.log('a>b>c actual:', getIds(getByClassnameHierarchy(root2, 'a>b>c')));
console.log('a>b>c expected:', ['c-1', 'c-2']);

console.log('b>c actual: ', getIds(getByClassnameHierarchy(root2, 'b>c')));
console.log('b>c expected:', ['c-1', 'c-2', 'c-3', 'c-4']);

console.log('b actual: ', getIds(getByClassnameHierarchy(root2, 'b')));
console.log('b expected:', ['b-1', 'b-2']);

console.log('a>c actual: ', getIds(getByClassnameHierarchy(root2, 'a>c')));
console.log('a>c expected:', []);
```

```html
<div id="root2">
  <div class="a" id="a-1">
    <div class="b" id="b-1">
      <div class="c" id="c-1"></div>
      <div class="c" id="c-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b" id="b-2">
    <div class="c" id="c-3"></div>
    <div class="c" id="c-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I've just added a few more samples below the function, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: So we are doing a DFS.. Can we do the same thing by level order traversal? (by maintaining queue?) Just curious what the PRO' and Con's would be via that approach!

Comment: @TechnoCorner I'm a bit unfamiliar with these notions (I just googled the terms because I didn't remember them). I'm confident there are different approaches to this, but this one should be straightforward and performant enough. [The article I've just read](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bfs-vs-dfs-binary-tree/) states that "if our problem is to search something that is more likely to closer to root, we would prefer BFS. And if the target node is close to a leaf, we would prefer DFS.". So I'm guessing DFS is fine here since it's kinda likely to be quite deep into the DOM (at least it can).

Comment: Thank you, i wil read through the article.

Also, looks like this test seems to be failing:


// gaps in the selector shouldn't return anything:
console.log('actual: ', getIds(getByClassnameHierarchy(root2, 'a>c')));
console.log(`a>c expected:` , `[]`, '\n');

Comment: If you use `a>c` it returns `[ 'c-1', 'c-2' ]` but the actual value is `[]`

Comment: @TechnoCorner See my edit, had to have a special case for level 0. Should be fine now, sorry about that.

Comment: It's amazing. Don't be sorry you're so awesome to help me out. Appreciate your time

Comment: @TechnoCorner No problem, that was a fun little challenge :) Make sure to check my very last edit if you haven't, there was still a minor bug. Good luck!

Comment: @Jeto what if the root div has class b, and its immediate child has class a and c.  shouldn't that be included in the result?  Why did you not start from the root but instead start from the child?

Comment: @techguy2000 Well, that was an old question, so couldn't remember, but anyway, I've edited the answer with a version that should fix that. Thanks for pointing it out :)